# Entity Framework: One to many with the same class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have the following requirement: There are basically two classes Object and Attribute. I want to model the database in such a way that one Object can have many Attributes which is easy to do. But the othe requirement is that one Object can also have many other Objects. How would that be possible to implement and what do I need to do in my Model Classes to achieve this?
So far I have this:

```
    public class Object
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }

    }

    public class Attribute
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public Object Object { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't let you have many attributes for an object by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just add new property to your object class, that targets the object you want, so something like this:

```
public class Object
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    public Object Object { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Object Object { get; set; }

}
```

but from the code provided, your Object class references just one instance of the Attribute class, so you dont have 1:N relation as you said you want, but rather 1:1! If you want the Object class to point to several Attributes and several Object Instances, the code should be something like this:

```
    public class Object
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Object ParentObject { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Object ParentObject { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your looking for is Many-to-many relationships for the Database.

You could structure it like this, which will give you one extra table.

```
   public class Object
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }

        }
        public class Attribute
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
           

        }
        public class ObjectAndAttribute
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
            public Object Object { get; set; }

        }
```